# Is there any method to fetch current running port of odoo server?

Tags: odoo, port, odoo-8

I need to fetch current port of odoo server? suggest any method or slution if any?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to get the port from,

If you want to access the port from Javascript. (maybe you're writing a Javascript extension). It's as easy as this:

```
window.location.port
```

In python (a little bit hacky but works)

```
>>> with open('/path/to/config/file.conf') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         if line.startswith('xmlrpc_port'):
...             port = line.split('=')[1].strip()
... 
>>> port
'8069'
```

Basically you just open the config file, read all the lines and get the line that contains the `xmlrpc_port` and extract the port number from it